# VBA Selecting specific rows based on list of relative row numbers and range

Tags: vba, excel

So I'm trying to make a sample selector.

The current variables I have are a range that has been specified by the user.

Settings.AmountColumn is a range that looks something along the lines of B1:H100. 
SampleRefArr is an array of row numbers, relative to the first row of the Settings.AmountColumn.

For example, if my SampleRefArr shows (3,4,7) then I will need to take the following ranges (B4:H4,B5:H5,B8:H8) and copy them to a new spreadsheet. I have built the following code but that does not select the right cells...

```
counter = UBound(SampleRefArr, 1)

For i = 1 To counter

    rowSelector = SampleRefArr(i) - Settings.AmountColumn.Cells(1, 1).Row + 2
    'Settings.AmountColumn.Cells(rowSelector, 1).EntireRow.Select
    Settings.AmountColumn(Cells(rowSelector, 1), Cells(rowSelector, 10)).Select
Next i
```

Comment: You wrote (3,4,7) would define the ranges (B4:H4,B5:H5,B8:H8), meaning that you have a shift of one row. I don' t see evidences of this shift anywhere. Am I missing something?

Comment: Probably a header row, this corresponds to data row 3

Comment: it would be like range("b2:h1000").row(SampleRefArray(0))

Comment: You should say which cells it does select. Is your array zero-based or one-based?

Comment: My array is zero based. So for index location 0 in the array, there is a value of '3', and for index location 1 there is a value of 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use this:

```
Sub RangeSelector(rng As Range, refArr As Variant)
    Intersect(rng, rng.Range("A" & Replace(Join(refArr, ","), ",", ",A")).EntireRow.Offset(1)).Select
End Sub
```

to be called like:

```
RangeSelector Range("B1:H100"), Array(3, 4, 7)
```

which would return cells "B4:H5" and "B8:H8" selected

Comment: Hi! i've got a bit of a problem with this code unfortunately...  when I run it on a different workbook it gives me the following error "application defined object defined error "

Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: it's because the `Select` method must be called upon a range in the currently _active_ worksheet. So you should add `rng.Parent.Activate` right before the `Intersect(rng, ...` statement. BTW you should avoid any coding based on `Select`/`Selection`/`Activate`/`ActiveXXX` and use fully qualified range references. For instance you could turn that `Sub` into a `Function` returning the wanted Range like: `Function RangeSelector(rng As Range, refArr As Variant) As Range\ Set RangeSelector = Intersect(rng, rng.Range("A" & Replace(Join(refArr, ","), ",", ",A")).EntireRow.Offset(1))\  'End Function`

Comment: Ok thanks for that! so for clarity, now when i can RangeSelector I get a range back, which I then later have to call select on?

Comment: If you leave it like a Sub() and make that little change (insert "rng.Parent.Activate" right before the "Intersect(rng, ..." statement), then you get a selected range. While if you turn it into a Function then you get back a range you can call "Select" upon

Comment: Yea I thought so.   Unfortunately it is still giving me the same error "Application-defined or Object-defined error".... this is now happening also on a separate sheet of the same work book...  It works on my original dataset on "sheet1" but fails on any other sheet or any other work book.
Thank you so much for your time by the way

Comment: that `rng.Parent.Activate` revision makes the `Sub` working for range on a different worksheet then the _active_ one but of the _same_ workbook, as I tested it. While for the `Function` you have to add a `someWorksheet.Activate` statement right before the `RangeSelector(Range("B1:H100"), Array(3, 4, 7)).Select` one in your "main" code. But, above all you have to avoid use of any `Select/Selection/Activate/ActiveXXX` pattern and go with fully qualified range references

Comment: Right... turns out that this is being caused by when my refArr is too long... specifically about 54 items. So strange..... there are no duplicates, and the rows are all contained within the dataset. My datarange is 435 rows long or so...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this?

```
counter = UBound(SampleRefArr, 1)

For i = LBound(samplrefarr,1) To counter
    With Settings.AmountColumn
        rowSelector = SampleRefArr(i) - .Cells(1, 1).Row + 2
        'Settings.AmountColumn.Cells(rowSelector, 1).EntireRow.Select
        .Range(.Cells(rowSelector, 1), .Cells(rowSelector, 10)).Select
    End With
Next i
```